# How to make first column of a row black and second column red

Tags: css

I would like to give a css class to a row
and i would like to make the first column black and the second column red. 
I dont want to use colgroup because this is a row specific action not whole table should be effected.

Comment: Can you not just give each cell a class and style with CSS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use:

```
td { color: black; }
td:nth-child(2) { color: red; }
```

Comment: Thisi s possible without CSS3 for better browser support.

Comment: @Qtax how about every odd rows second column? Would be nested? `tr:nth-child(even) { td:nth-child(2) { color: red; }}`

Answer (score 9):

This is possible without CSS3 !

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yu5/1/

**CSS**

```
tr.special_row td {
    background-color: #000;
}

tr.special_row td + td {
    background-color: #f00;
}

tr.special_row td+td+td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr class="special_row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not exactly what @rematnarab was looking for. I didn't keep in mind, that not the whole table should be affected. edited `tr` to a more specific rule.

Comment: Just a note: I was in the need of your **PREVIOUS** Version of the code. +1 for review log!

Answer (score 3):

> ... this is a row specific action not whole table should be effected.

Then applying different styles to your first and second column of the given row could be useful:

```
<style type="text/css">
    td.first
    {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    td.second
    {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">1st row, 1st column</td>
        <td class="second">1st row, 2nd column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2nd row, 1st column</td>
        <td>2nd row, 2nd column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 Whoops. You are right! --> `not whole table should be effected`

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3 you can use the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class.

See [the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) for how to use it.
Also, as of early 2019, there's barely a reason [not to use CSS3 selectors](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 types of CSS.
For each row you add the CSS you want.

Comment: 1/ Which type of CSS? Do you mean CSS rules? 2/ Are you saying that you add style attributes on the first two cells of each row? Better separate CSS from HTML whenever it's possible (and it's possible here)

Comment: exactly, this css can reuse in the future